# Php mysql_fetch add me the row number at the begining of each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

This is my php code:

```
 $query = Select * from tablename;
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die((mysql_error()));
 $count = 0;
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){


   while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


      $json_output[$count]=$row;

      $count ++;

   }


}


 $output = json_encode($json_output);

 $output = str_replace('[{', '{', $output);
 $output = str_replace('}]', '}', $output);

 echo $output;
```

And this is a part of my php output:

```
 {"0":{"0":"2","Gi_Id":"2","1":"sample_name.jpg","Gi_nome_file":"sample_name.jpg","2":"sample_name","Gi_Pseudonimo":"s. name","3":"sample name","
```

as you can see, there are the tag "0", "1" , "2", etc that represent the column number ( "0" for Gi_Id , "1" for Gi_nome_file etc) of my sql table.
Why there are this duplicates? 
Probally i can manage this output ignoring the duplicate single cell value, but i want to undestand how to fix that.

I think that the problem is this row of my code:

```
 $json_output[$count]=$row;
```

but i don't find another way to get all my table data.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Using mysql_fetch_assoc i dont have the duplicate but remains the number at the begining of each row, my output is the following:

```
{"0":{"Gi_Id":"2","Gi_nome_file":"sample_name.jpg","Gi_Pseudonimo":"s. name",
```

and for the row number 2 i have:

```
{"1":{"Gi_Id":"3","Gi_nome_file":"sample_name.jpg","Gi_Pseudonimo":"s. name",
```

and for the row number 3 i have:

```
{"2":{"Gi_Id":"4","Gi_nome_file":"sample_name.jpg","Gi_Pseudonimo":"s. name",
```

...

and for the row number n i have:

```
{"n":{"Gi_Id":"n+1","Gi_nome_file":"sample_name.jpg","Gi_Pseudonimo":"s. name",
```

etc
i would like to remove the 
    {"0": , {"1": ,{"2":, {"3":
at the begining of each row , how i can do this?

Comment: Read what `mysql_fetch_array()` returns... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: How i can use  in place of mysql_fetch_array( ), to resolve my problem?

Comment: You read the manual page and saw what it returned and saw the **See Also** links?

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc, resolve my problem for the duplicate.  Now i would try to remove the {"0": , {"1" ecc  indicating the $count value (the $json_output array key)

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you have example json you want it to look like?

Comment: this is my output now 
{"0":{"Gi_Id":"2","Gi_nome_file":"sample_name.jpg","Gi_Pseudonimo":"s. name",
and for the row number 2 i have:
{"1":{"Gi_Id":"2","Gi_nome_file":"sample_name.jpg","Gi_Pseudonimo":"s. name",
etc

i would like to remove the {"0": , {"1": ,{"2":, {"3":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem:

this is the solution:

```
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die((mysql_error()));
```

$json_output = array();
$count = 0;

$response["Prova"] = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){


    $json_output[$count]=$row;

    // push single rating into final response array


    $count ++;

}

array_push($response["Prova"], $json_output);


}

//alla fine aggiungo il tag di successo
$json_output["success"] = 1;

$output = json_encode(array($response));
//rimuovo le parentesi graffe per far si che non mi dia problemi con il json di android
$output = str_replace('[{', '{', $output);
$output = str_replace('}]', '}', $output);

echo $output;
```